# Run nested JUnit 5 tests with Maven Surefire

Tags: maven, junit, nested, maven-surefire-plugin, junit5

I'm trying to use JUnit 5 in my side project as a trial before migrating my main project. I'd like to use @Nested tests to make my test classes cleaner. 
Everything is fine when I ran my test suite as a whole. However, as soon as I try running just a single test, @Nested ones are not executed.

```
mvn -Dtest=com.mycompany.test.MyTest surefire:test
```

Is there any way of getting it to run the selected class and all @Nested ones?

Using JUnit 5.1.0, JUnit platform 1.1.0

```
<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
        <version>${org.junit.platform.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${org.junit.version}</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Test class:

```
public class MyTest {

  @Test
  public void thisTestExecutes() { }

  @Nested
  public class NestedTests {
    @Test
    public void thisTestDoesnt() { }
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a bug in our Surefire provider to me. Can you please open an issue on GitHub? https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/new

Comment: Thanks Marc, just did that: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1343

Comment: Have you tried to update the maven-surefire-plugin version to 2.22.0 or later? (see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53433663/maven-not-running-junit-5-tests/53433724#53433724)

Answer (score 9):

To run all nested classes you just need to add an "*" at end of class name. Something like:

```
mvn -Dtest=com.mycompany.test.MyTest\* surefire:test
```

or

```
mvn -Dtest=com.mycompany.test.MyTest* surefire:test
```

Comment: I had to remove that backslash for it to work, maybe because I'm on Windows, but the * did not need escaping for me.

Comment: to run only one nested class, `-Dtest:OuterClass$NestedClass`

Comment: to run only one test in a nested class , `-Dtest:OuterClass$NestedClass#methodName`

Comment: @AlexanderTaylor this is implementation specific, it can change in any java version; but I do not know of a better way

Answer (score 0):

Facing with same issue, then realized my parent test class name and .java file name are different. I changed my test class name to my .java file name with right click > Refactor > Rename (for possible reference issue). Lastly run my test with following command:

`mvn -Dtest=com.mycompany.test.MyTest*`

By the way I'm using maven-surefire-plugin 2.22.2 version.

Answer (score 0):

Whole problem is that nested tests are classes compiled the same way as the anonymous classes with a name containing **$**. The Surefire and Failsafe excludes these by the default pattern

```
**/*$*
```

If you use lambda then these exclusions become more and more important.
This should work as well:

```
mvn test -Dexcludes=nonetest
```