# Maven not running JUnit 5 tests

Tags: java, maven, junit, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm trying to get a simple junit test running with maven but it is not detecting any tests. Where am I going wrong? The project directory

```
Project -> src -> test-> java -> MyTest.java
```

Results :

```
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.buildproftest.ecs</groupId>
    <artifactId>buildprofiletest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <debug>false</debug>
                    <optimize>true</optimize>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Junit test case

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class MyTest {
    @Test
    public void printTest() {
        System.out.println("Running JUNIT test");
    }
}
```

The response is that there are no test cases to run.

Comment: It's good your test method is public, but the class can be package-private for JUnit 5+. See also https://www.baeldung.com/maven-cant-find-junit-tests

Answer (score 142, accepted):

According to the annotation (`import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`), you are trying to run JUnit 5 tests with Maven. According to the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html), you have to add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Your version of Maven comes with a version of `maven-surefire-plugin` which does not support JUnit 5. You could update your Maven to the latest version. You could also set the version of the `maven-surefire-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <!-- JUnit 5 requires Surefire version 2.22.0 or higher -->
    <version>2.22.0</version>
</plugin>
```

See the [junit5-samples for this information](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/blob/r5.3.1/junit5-jupiter-starter-maven/pom.xml).

See the [Maven Surefire Plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin) artifact in a Maven repository. At version `3.0.0-M3` as of 2019-01.

Comment: I added the dependency and ran mvn clean test but no test run still. Thanks.

Comment: Why have you also the JUnit 4.12 as dependency? It might be the problem. Try to remove it.

Comment: I've removed that now and still no joy. I ran the test through my IDE independent of maven and it does run. Thanks

Comment: I could reproduce the problem and fix it with the version of `maven-surefire-plugin`.

Comment: Manged to solve it, I wasnt specifying the version of the sure fire plugin. I specified 3.0.0-M1 and it worked. Thank you

Comment: Tip: As of JUnit 5 version 5.4.0, you can use the new convenient single Maven artifact named *JUnit Jupiter (Aggregator)* that in turn gets you several related artifacts needed to write and run JUnit 5 tests: [`junit-jupiter`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter)

Comment: Just stumbled upon this answer. Is 3.0.0-M3 considered stable? I am not sure about that suffix in the version number and didn't find any information about the version scheme of the maven plugins.

Comment: @SebastianS The official page claims, this is a stable version: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/download.cgi

Comment: It worked for me using the junit-jupiter dependency and the version 3.0.0 of the Surefire plugin; however, only the test classes located in the root package are run (by root package I mean the one having the same name as the groupId in the pom)

Comment: Adding dependency `junit-jupiter-engine` did the trick for me. I had had already `junit-jupiter-api` and `maven-surefire-plugin`.

Answer (score 57):

## tl;dr

Add two dependencies to your project:

- *JUnit Jupiter (Aggregator)*
- *Maven Surefire Plugin*

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>5.9.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

… and:

```xml
<!-- https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/dependency-info.html -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
  <type>maven-plugin</type>
</dependency>
```

## `junit-jupiter` — the simpler archetype for JUnit 5

The [Answer by LaurentG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53433724/642706) seems to be correct, but a bit outdated.

As of JUnit 5.4, you can **replace those multiple Maven artifacts**:

- `junit`
- `junit-jupiter-api`
- `junit-jupiter-engine`

…with a single artifact:

- [`junit-jupiter`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter)

…to run JUnit 5 tests.

This artifact is an aggregate of other artifacts, a convenient wrapper to simplify your POM file. See [this repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter).

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>5.9.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

This gives you all you need to write and run JUnit 5 *Jupiter* tests.

## `maven-surefire-plugin`

You would also need the [*Surefire* plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin) as shown in that [other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53433724/642706). Be sure to get the latest version, as Surefire has had some important fixes/enhancements recently.

See [this list](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/dependency-info.html) of dependency declarations for Maven, Buildr, Ivy, Grape, Grails, SBT, and Leiningen. To quote the Maven config:

```xml
<!-- https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/dependency-info.html -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
  <type>maven-plugin</type>
</dependency>
```

## `junit-vintage-engine` for JUnit 3 & 4 tests

If you have old JUnit 3 or JUnit 4 [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) tests that you want to continue to run, add another dependency, [`junit-vintage-engine`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.vintage/junit-vintage-engine).

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.vintage/junit-vintage-engine -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.9.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: +1 for the requirement of junit-vintage to run legacy Junit 3 / 4 tests - had upgraded surefire and junit yet my tests were not getting executed . introducing junit-vintage dependency did the trick

Comment: adding the surefire plugin is the *main* thing. The junit dependencies don't do the job by themselves.

Comment: @foo Good point. I enhanced that section.

Answer (score 12):

- I was having a similar problem where the junit `@Test` annotation would work but not the org.junit.jupiter.api.Test `@Test` annotation.

#### The solution:

- [THIS](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html) is mavens official guide on how to confugure the `maven-surefire-plugin` and make sure that is uses the proper `junit-jupiter-engine`
- The guide is a little confusing so, this is how I got it to work

**1)** add the engine dependency to the dependencies block:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

**2)** add the engine dependency to maven-surefire:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M6</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                    <version>5.6.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the Junit 5 documentation, this is what we need to execute the tests by using `mvn test`:

```xml
<!-- ... -->
<dependencies>
    <!-- ... -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- ... -->
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<!-- ... -->
```

Sources:

- https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven-engines-configure
- https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/blob/r5.9.2/junit5-jupiter-starter-maven/pom.xml

Answer (score 2):

For me (all tests are using Junit 5) , it was enough to just use version 3.0.0-M7 for surefire plugin in the plugins section. No need to add surefire plugin to dependencies and i only had org.junit.jupiter.junit-jupiter in my dependencies, no other jupiter dependencies.

Comment: This onw worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Add "include" in configuration section for maven surfire, your test should end with Test.java and it should work

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks mate! --  I was tearing my hair out over this :(  --- I can't believe they have **re-introduced** the **stupid** JUnit naming-convention from ages back :((( -- how ridiculous!  :(((

Comment: So, to avoid this bugger, we should always add this now:

<includes><include>**/*.java</include></includes>

Answer (score 1):

I recently discovered that I had to add the prefix "test" on my tests methods in order to get my tests executed by maven.

```
@Test
public void testStringsAreEqual() {
    var aString = "Walrus Code";

    Assertions.assertEquals(aString, "Walrus Code");
}
```

Otherwise the tests are ignored... This is part of my pom:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>11</source>
                <target>11</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.myapp.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, on top of the accepted answer with 2 changes (maven-surefire plugin version and artifacts of org.junit.jupiter), I had to add one more change. (Java version used: 11)

Even though org.jacoco.agent was a part of my dependencies list, it needed to be added within < dependencyManagement > tag as well. This seemed to have resolved any underlying version/enforced the dependency automatically.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
            <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
            <classifier>runtime</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me not ran tests were due to surefire plugin not being ran at all. This was due to 2 reasons.

1. I declared sunfire plugin in

   build->pluginmanagement->plugins

   instead of just

   build->plugins
2. My  type was pom instead of jar.

I know these might sound like errors done almost on purpose but it was a result of novice maven user creating pom.xml via copy paste from different projects. I also know that my symptoms were different from what author described (plugin not ran at all instead of no tests found) but I believe it fits well to the thread topic and this solution might help some people.